# Devise not logging in user in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rspec-rails

I have a request spec like this, (it uses capybara and factory_girl DSL's)

```
describe 'An authenticated user' do

  let(:user) do
    create(:user)
  end

  before do
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in 'email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Log in'
  end

  it 'should ...
```

The spec fails and I get this entry in test.log

```
 Started POST "/user/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-04 13:45:04 +0530
 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"user15@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I get the same even when I replace the capybara block with

```
post user_session_path, { email: user.email, password: user.password }
```

The ActiveRecord: 0.0ms bothers me, as it may not even be querying if the user exists. Using 'save_and_open_page' shows me 'Invalid email or password'.

I'm doing nothing fancy. It's just plain devise generated pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was my misunderstanding of the params that Devise::SessionsController accepts. This works.

```
before do
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in 'user[email]', with: user.email
  fill_in 'user[password]', with: user.password
  click_button 'Log in'
end
```

and so does this,

```
post user_session_path, user: { email: user.email, password: user.password }
```

Sorry for the mistake!